# Excel three column duplication and averaging

Tags: excel, duplicates, average

I need to average data (3rd column) corresponding to a specific latitude and longitude(1st and 2nd columns). The results are then outputted to columns 4,5,6.

Sample data and manual analysis is posted bellow. I think I need Index, Iferror or Vlookup. Most of the other questions dealing with this kind of work only typically consider 1 variable, not two.

```
Latitude Longitude  Data  UniqueLat UniqueLong  Average of data
24.4000 -82.5000    13.1        24.4000 -82.5000    13.15
24.4000 -82.5000    13.2        24.4000 -82.4000    15.25
24.4000 -82.4000    17.8        24.5000 -82.4000    13.4
24.4000 -82.4000    12.7        24.5000 -82.1000    14.56
24.5000 -82.4000    13.4        24.6000 -82.0000    18
24.5000 -82.1000    16              
24.5000 -82.1000    15.1                
24.5000 -82.1000    13.3                
24.5000 -82.1000    15.1                
24.5000 -82.1000    13.3                
24.6000 -82.0000    15.6                
24.6000 -82.0000    20.4
```

I have a second problem related to this original question;

I need to compare my list of latitude/longitude (columns 4 and 5) with the values outputted from the Pivot table containing the latitude/longitude data (columns 1 and 2) and its associated data (column 3). This associated data I need to ascribe to the relevant latitude and longitude in column 6.

I have tried to use the index functionality etc but have had little luck.

Let me know if you can help at all with this second part.

```
DatabaseLat DatabaseLon Data        Lat      Lon    CopiedData
31.2    -87.9   5                   30.5    -87.1   3
31.9    -88.3   6                   31.9    -88.4   10
31.9    -88.4   10                  54      -87.1
31.1    -87.2   2                   31.2    -87.9   5
30.5    -87.1   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a pivot table:

1. Select all the data (including headers) in columns Latitude, Longitude, and Data.
2. Choose `Insert` > `PivotTable`.
3. Drag `Latitude` and `Longitude` into the `Row Labels` section.
4. Choose `PivotTable Tools` > `Design` > `Report Layout` > `Show in Tabular Form` **and** `Repeat All Item Levels`.  Also choose to turn off `Grand Totals` and `Subtotals`.
5. Drag the `Data` column into the `Values` section.
6. Hit the drop-down for `Data` and change the `Value Field Settings...` to average.

All said and told, the results should like this:

[image: PivotTable]

Comment: Beautiful, worked like a treat!
Note excel 2011 mac removed "repeat all item labels" as far as I could tell.
If you find yourself in a similar position.. http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html

Comment: Hi jason, if you could have a look at the second part of the question that would be most appreciated!! Your insight is sublime

Answer (score 0):

For the first part I would use an averageifs formula.

For the second part if you are guaranteed that the list you are looking up is unique (I think it is from what you said) you could just use a sumifs to then find the value next to that lat and long.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for answering
Im not quite sure how I would go about using the sumifs formula for this problem. Would it compare both sets of latitude and longitude even if they are different lengths?

Comment: Using the data you posted (Assuming it is starting at A1) I just entered this formula in G2 and dragged down and got the same results as you posted: =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D2,B:B,E2)

Comment: Amazing thanks for the help, would upvote but not got the reputation yet :)

Comment: All good mate, just glad I could help you out. Just remember though, ANY duplication on A and B together will sum the values and give you an answer you are not expecting, it MUST be unique.